# Navigate to next jsp page without need of hyperlink clicking

Tags: html, jsp

I was using the tag below to navigate to the next jsp page,

```
 href=<%= "\"Success.jsp?name=" + rs.getString(1) + "\"" %> >Success Click to continue
```

but I want the same thing to be done without need of clicking the hyperlink

please help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will redirect without any hyperlinks.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Redirection</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Page Redirection</h1>
</center>
<%
   // New location to be redirected
   String site = new String("http://www.photofuntoos.com");
   response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
   response.setHeader("Location", site); 
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its working but I want to pass rs.getString(1)  value to the next page

Comment: @SampathSam : then your question is already answered here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141674/jsp-passing-parameters-between-jsp-pages